# Framework for coding simple iOS + Android app that allows push notifications

Tags: android, ios, framework

I'm coding an app that works fine as a website but would be much better if it supported push notifications to a smartphone (and ideally if it could be opened from the phone's home screen).

I am new to mobile development and want to be able to develop the app in JavaScript and then deploy to both Android and iOS.

The only functionality I care about that isn't available on a basic website is push notifications.

My understanding is that if I were willing to focus just on Android (and abandon iOS users), I could just code a Progressive Web App (PWA), because [Android apparently supports push notifications](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/codelabs/push-notifications/). Maybe someday iOS will, too, but I don't want to wait.

I looked into React Native (the framework used by the Facebook apps, Instagram, Pinterest, Walmart, Tesla, etc), because it enables deploying to iOS and Android from a single JavaScript project, but it looks like [push notifications](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/pushnotificationios) are more complicated and would require platform-specific native code rather than JavaScript.

**Which "Write Once, Run Everywhere" frameworks (ideally using JavaScript) support push notifications to both iOS and Android?**

Comment: https://flutter.dev/ uses https://dart.dev/ (C-style syntax). See also Flutter Web https://flutter.dev/multi-platform/web, https://reactnative.dev/, https://necolas.github.io/react-native-web/, https://expo.dev/, https://cordova.apache.org/, Xamarin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ionic Framework allows through a Cordova plugin to push notifications, so it achieves your "write once and run everywhere" criteria .

> Build progressive web and native mobile apps for every major app store, with one codebase. Ionic works and looks beautiful wherever it runs.

Ionic is an open source mobile application framework.

> Ionic Framework is a 100% free and open source project, licensed under
>   MIT. It will always remain free to use, powered by a massive
>   world-wide community.

It allows you to build applications with Typescript, AngularJS, Javascript, and HTML5.

I've built my first app in a matter of days, without prior experience in Typescript and AngularJS.

Last but not least it supports Push Notifications via a [plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/push/) to:

> Android, Browser, iOS, Windows

Comment: That sure sounds like what I’ve been looking for. From the plugin docs, it looks like push notifications are still destined to be difficult, but I guess that’s the current state of technology. Thanks.

Comment: On my app, I didn't use push notification so I can't comment I am afraid, but the rest of the framework seems quite easy to understand.